Docker run doesn't work even through it can pull image and docker is running
This is my pc config.
pegasus@pegasus:~$ uname -a
Linux pegasus 6.8.0-36-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jun 10 10:49:14 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
pegasus@pegasus:~$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 24.04 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="24.04"
VERSION="24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat)"
VERSION_CODENAME=noble
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=noble
LOGO=ubuntu-logo

I've setup my docker in the way mentioned here.
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup proxy.example.com on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
But currently after doing sudo apt upgrade I'm facing the issue of not being able to run most of the docker images even after pulling it.
pegasus@pegasus:~$ docker images
REPOSITORY    TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
ubuntu        22.04     8a3cdc4d1ad3   9 days ago      77.9MB
hello-world   latest    d2c94e258dcb   14 months ago   13.3kB
pegasus@pegasus:~$ docker run ubuntu:22.04
pegasus@pegasus:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

pegasus@pegasus:~$ systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-07-07 10:40:21 +06; 7min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 3589 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 16
     Memory: 112.9M (peak: 115.2M)
        CPU: 695ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─3589 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

জুলাই 07 10:40:20 pegasus systemd[1]: Starting docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine...
জুলাই 07 10:40:20 pegasus dockerd[3589]: time="2024-07-07T10:40:20.790924612+06:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
জুলাই 07 10:40:20 pegasus dockerd[3589]: time="2024-07-07T10:40:20.873556063+06:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
জুলাই 07 10:40:20 pegasus dockerd[3589]: time="2024-07-07T10:40:20.875291689+06:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
জুলাই 07 10:40:21 pegasus dockerd[3589]: time="2024-07-07T10:40:21.049643248+06:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip>
জুলাই 07 10:40:21 pegasus dockerd[3589]: time="2024-07-07T10:40:21.139310021+06:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
জুলাই 07 10:40:21 pegasus dockerd[3589]: time="2024-07-07T10:40:21.159863331+06:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=c8af8eb containerd-snapshotter=false storage-driver=overlay2 version>
জুলাই 07 10:40:21 pegasus dockerd[3589]: time="2024-07-07T10:40:21.160313458+06:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
জুলাই 07 10:40:21 pegasus dockerd[3589]: time="2024-07-07T10:40:21.216982812+06:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
জুলাই 07 10:40:21 pegasus systemd[1]: Started docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine.

How can I fix it?

docker run ubuntu:22.04 will do nothing. It starts a shell and sees that no TTY is attached and terminates. So that's as expected. If you add the -it option, it runs it interactively, like this:
docker run -it ubuntu:22.04

Then you should get into a shell in the container. As soon as you exit the shell, the container will terminate. That's how containers work. They only run for as long as the process inside is running.
The reason docker ps doesn't show anything is that it only shows running containers and you don't have any. I you do
docker ps -a

it'll also show terminated containers and you should see your Ubuntu container in an exited state.
